# Fortran - subtraction with zero leads to increasingly negative results

Tags: fortran

I am not sure what's happening, I have a simple loop with a subtraction and addition. At some point during the loop `c` becomes zero and stays zero until the end, so it shouldn't have any effect in the subtraction. However, after `c` becomes zero `array1` keeps decreasing. I know of the floating point problems, but shouldn't 0 be 0? Also when I try to print the value of `c` I get `0.0000000E+00`. array b holds positive and negative real numbers in the order of 0.00001, array c holds only positive numbers in the order of 0.00002. These arrays have 3 dimensions because they represent a 2-d map over time, think daily climate data for example.

```
INTEGER :: ntime
ntime=100000
REAL,DIMENSION(1,1,ntime) :: array1,b,c
array1(:,:,:)=0

DO itime=1,ntime

    array1(1,1,itime)=array1(1,1,itime-1)+b(1,1,itime)-c(1,1,itime-1)

    IF (itime .ge. 15000)
        c(1,1,itime)=0
      ENDIF
ENDO
```

When I add to the loop an IF condition that only includes `c` in the operation if `c` is greater than 0, than the values of `array1` look better but I still don't get the correct result. The value of `array1` at the end of the loop should be the initial value of **`array1`** + the sum of all values in `b` - sum of all values in `c`. So the biggest problem must the the subtraction of 0 but also something else is not working. I should add that `b` is an array made by subtracting REAL numbers. Is there some compounding floating point error in additions?

Comment: your question is rather vague. There is nothing wrong with this code syntactically, so if there is an error, it should be semantic and the information provided here is nowhere close enough to detect the bug.

Comment: There is actually a bug in your code: `array1(1,1,itime-1)` is undefined for `itime = 1`.

Comment: @King that's correct, good catch. I think the bug was in the outer loop which is not shown here.